# Intersection of Hyperbolas

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, nonlinear-system

I have two hyperbolas, given in the form:

$$\tag{1}A_1x^2+2B_1xy+C_1y^2+2D_1x+2E_1y+F_1=0$$
$$\tag{2}A_2x^2+2B_2xy+C_2y^2+2D_2x+2E_2y+F_2=0$$

With $A_1=A_2=0$.
I wish to attain all intersection points. I saw [this](http://www.analyzemath.com/HyperbolaProblems/hyperbola_intersection.html) example, but my representation is different. In addition, somehow [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form) transformation does not seem to work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: There can be 2 real, one double or a single complex root & conjugate.

Comment: Are you looking for a general formula?  Or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: @Narasimham, that doesn't sound quite right unless I'm misreading what you said.  There can be 1 real solution (e.g. $xy + y^2 + x + y + 1 = 0$ and $-2xy + y^2 + x + y + 1 = 0$) or 3 real solutions (e.g. $xy + y^2 + x + y + 1 = 0$ and $2xy -12y^2-3x-31y+37=0$), etc.

Comment: @tilper I have a set of hyperbolas of this form ($A_i=0$), and I'm looking for a general formula to find all intersection points of any two hyperbolas in the set.

Comment: In the last example you gave in the question you chose axes rotated hyperbolas without an $xy$ term,

Comment: @omerbp when *considering double branches*  as distinct the number of roots can  increase to 4, and minimum two real roots.. Can you upload the graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $A_1=A_2=0$ leads to a cubic equation. They are at least one or up to three intersection points :

[image]

The general case, valid not only for two hyperbolas but for two quadratic curves, leads to a quartic equation, so from zero up to four intersection points.

[image]

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I looked for. Thanks!

Comment: Just a correction, the term $k_1$ should be $2(E_1 D_2 + F_1 B_2 - 2 E_2 D_1-F_2B_1)$

Comment: Yes some terms are missing. I will correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is voluminous, found by Cramer's Rule solving for 2 unknowns from 2 equations.  Roots are as quadratic equation depending on sign of quantity under the radical 
$$
(-2 B2^2 C1 D1 + 2 B1 B2 C2 D1 + A2 C1 C2 D1 - A1 C2^2 D1 + 
    2 B1 B2 C1 D2 - A2 C1^2 D2 - 2 B1^2 C2 D2 + A1 C1 C2 D2 + 
    A2 B2 C1 E1 - 2 A2 B1 C2 E1 + A1 B2 C2 E1 + A2 B1 C1 E2 - 
    2 A1 B2 C1 E2 + A1 B1 C2 E2)/(-4 A2 B1 B2 C1 + 4 A1 B2^2 C1 + 
    A2^2 C1^2 + 4 A2 B1^2 C2 - 4 A1 B1 B2 C2 - 2 A1 A2 C1 C2 + 
    A1^2 C2^2)  + ..... + \sqrt {...}
$$
EDIT 1:
Considering a single brach it may be like one of three situations:

[image: Hyp ntrxn]

But for  two branches, there is a situation of double the number of roots/intersections  as may be in a quadratic equation.

Comment: Do you mean [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule)? Any point to a valuable explanation?

Comment: Changed spelling.

Comment: My hope is that since $A_i=0$ this expression can be simplified....

Comment: To an extent may be by dividing by $ F$ s , $A_i =0$  but depends on the discriminant basically.

Comment: Do you refer to $D$ or $\Delta$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Quadratic_equation)? Anyway, it holds that $x_c=0$ (in the same notations)